# Variable substitution in docker-compose command

Tags: docker-compose

I need to pass env variable from file to a command in a docker-compose but it seems impossible.
So I try first with environment var but it doesn't work again. How can I do that?

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  nginx-service-xxx:
    image: service-xxx-nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always

  service-xxx:
    image: service-xxx:latest
#    env_file:
#        - db-settings.env
    environment:
      - PORT=80
      - PG-HOST=192.168.0.101
      - PG-DATABASE=xxx
      - PG-USER=postgres
      - PG-PASSWORD=postgres
    restart: always
    command: python xxx/main.py --port=$$PORT --pg-host=$$PG-HOST --pg-database=$$PG-DATABASE --pg-user=$$PG-USER --pg-password=$$PG-PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to move the complexity of the command to a docker entry point.
First, you need to add the following entry point to your project (make it executable)

```
#!/bin/bash -e

case $1 in

  web)
    python xxx/main.py --port=$PORT --pg-host=$PG-HOST --pg-database=$PG-DATABASE --pg-user=$PG-USER --pg-password=$PG-PASSWORD
  ;;

  *)
    exec "$@"
  ;;

esac

exit 0
```

update the docker file for your service

```
From base-image

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

update compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx-service-xxx:
    image: service-xxx-nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: always

  service-xxx:
    image: service-xxx:latest
    environment:
      - PORT=80
      - PG-HOST=192.168.0.101
      - PG-DATABASE=xxx
      - PG-USER=postgres
      - PG-PASSWORD=postgres
    restart: always
    command: web
```

Comment: A few question: 1.In this way, if I push the image to dockerhub env are visible? 2.I never see bash script with exec "$@", esac.. can you explain or post a link? 3. I try to echo directly in the command and it doesn't work, so I came to the conclusion that env var are only for compose and are not passed to docker container, is it wrong? because you use it in the docker container with bash

Comment: 1- the values of the env vars will not be included in the docker image (you need to pass them from the command line or docker-compose). 2- `exec "$@"` will execute whatever in $@ if you pass another command other than `web` see this for more info https://www.learnshell.org/en/Special_Variables. 3 vars should be passed from docker-compose to the docker container during the creation time. to. verify that  you can execute these commands `docker exec -it ${container_name} printenv` this will print all the defined vars in the container (you also can use docker inspect $container)